# name 'user' is not defined mentions

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to get when a user pings another user! Get the users mention and add a point into the database! Although User is not defined! And cant register any points for the user getting pinged!

```
import sqlite3
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "ping")

POINTS = 0

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    db = sqlite3.connect("ping.sqlite")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main(
        user_id TEXT,
        points INTERGER
        )
        ''')
    print("Looking for Pings!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    USER = user.mention.id
    db = sqlite3.connect("ping.sqlite")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_id FROM main WHERE user_id = {USER}")
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        sql = ("INSERT INTO main(user_id, points) VALUES(?,?)")
        val = (USER, POINTS)
    elif result is not None:
        sql = ("UPDATE main SET channel_id = ? WHERE guild_id = ?")
        val = (ctx.guild.id, channel.id)
    cursor.execute(sql, val)
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if len(message.mentions) > 0:
        all_pinged_users = [user for user in message.mentions]
        #it will give all pinged user object in all_pinged_users and you can do anything with that!
    else:
        #no user is pinged
```

you can use this simple if statement to find if any user is pinged in the message! and the [message.mentions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) is in the type of list of all pinged users in that specific message
you can also iterate through the `message.mentions` to get all pinged user